# MapKit Tracking , Filter Latitude Longitude And Get the Address From Current Area in iOS

Tags: ios, mapkit

Subject " Travel Tracker "

1.Is there any way to track the current location and get the address of the current location directly from the application.

2.And how to draw the route from where to user start travel and where to user stop travel.

3.Main thing is i want to display the address of the current place.

4.Please anyone can you guide me in this activity.

Comment: please do search before posting a question! There are several answers available already!Though giving a link for drawing a route on map - http://www.raywenderlich.com/13160/using-the-google-places-api-with-mapkit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the Current location by using `CLLocationManager`

In `.h`

```
CLLocationManager *locationManager;
CLLocationCoordinate2D currentLocation;
```

In `.m`

```
 if (!locationManager) {

    locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    locationManager.delegate = (id)self;
    locationManager.distanceFilter = 100;
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
}

[locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
```

In `CLLocationManagerDelegate`

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation {

    currentLocation = newLocation.coordinate;
}
```

By using current location latitude and longitude you can get address.

```
CLGeocoder *geocoder = [[CLGeocoder alloc] init];

CLLocation *location = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:currentLocation.latitude longitude:currentLocation.longitude];

[geocoder reverseGeocodeLocation:location completionHandler:^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error) {

    if (error) {
        NSLog(@"failed with error: %@", error);
        return;
    }

    if(placemarks.count > 0) {

        NSString *MyAddress = @"";
        NSString *city = @"";

        CLPlacemark *placemark = [placemarks objectAtIndex:0];

        if([placemark.addressDictionary objectForKey:@"FormattedAddressLines"] != NULL)
            MyAddress = [[placemark.addressDictionary objectForKey:@"FormattedAddressLines"] componentsJoinedByString:@", "];
        else
            MyAddress = @"Address Not founded";

      NSLog (@"Address : %@",MyAddress);
    }
}];
```

Comment: It working fine can you explain me once. Because i little confused but your coding worked well :)